# Oauth signature, REST API

Tags: php, api, oauth

I am attempting to access the fat secret API.

https://platform.fatsecret.com/api/

I am attempting to create an Oauth signature using the secret key given by fat secret. When I try access the URL to grab the data I get an error saying my Oauth signature is invalid.

I create the signiture using base64_encode and then hash hmac using sha1.

Here is my code with the secret key blanked out, am I creating the signature in an incorrect way? Or can anyone see where I am going wrong.

Thank you

```
<?php
$requestTokenUrl = "http://platform.fatsecret.com/rest/server.api";
$oauth_consumer_key = "925f5e1a8b674a70b52eabf15f3265e7"; 
$nonce = md5(mt_rand());
$outh_signature = '';
$oauthSignatureMethod = "HMAC-SHA1"; 
$oauthTimestamp = time();
$oauthVersion = "1.0";
$secret_key = "My Secret Key";

$sigKey= $consumer_key . "&";

$sigBase = "method=food.get" . rawurlencode($requestTokenUrl) . "&"
    . rawurlencode("oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($oauth_consumer_key)
    . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce)
    . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($oauthSignatureMethod)
    . "&oauth_timestamp=" . $oauthTimestamp
    . "&oauth_version=" . $oauthVersion);

$oauthSig = base64_encode(hash_hmac('sha1', $secret_key, true));

$requestUrl = $requestTokenUrl . "?"
    . "food_id=33691"
    . "&method=food.get"
    . "&oauth_consumer_key=" . rawurlencode($oauth_consumer_key)
    . "&oauth_nonce=" . rawurlencode($nonce)
    . "&oauth_signature=" . rawurlencode($oauthSig)
    . "&oauth_signature_method=" . rawurlencode($oauthSignatureMethod)
    . "&oauth_timestamp=" . rawurlencode($oauthTimestamp)
    . "&oauth_version=" . rawurlencode($oauthVersion);

var_dump($requestUrl);
```

Comment: I think your signature base is missing the food_id parameter that you are passing in your request. I always found it helpful to use this tool from Google to test if the signature I was generating code matched the expected signature: http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look you are using the $sigBase for anything, and it's missing a few parts. Consult the OAuth 1.0a standard to see all the parts and how they are constructed: http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5849#section-3.4. Once you have your signature base constructed, use `hmac_hash('sha1', $sigBase, $secret_key)` to sign the base with your secret key. I don't think base64 encoding is required, just the hashing, unless fatsecret requires it.